# PHP function fetching array value

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I had this data (refer 2nd image below) and php function that fetch those data's then insert into the database. Somehow the function not manage to insert `$outletID`, it manage to loop 3 times and data insert into it, but at column `outletID` it insert `Array` as a value. Any idea what Im doing wrong here?

[image: ra]

[image]

```js
function addRevenueAccounts(){
  global $Obj;  
  $recipeTypeID = (isset($_POST['recipeTypeID']) ? $_POST['recipeTypeID'] : '');
  $outletID     = (isset($_POST['outletID']) ? $_POST['outletID'] : ''); 
  $accountID    = (isset($_POST['accountID']) ? $_POST['accountID'] : '');

  $countOutletID = sizeof($outletID);
  for($x=0; $x< $countOutletID; $x++ ){

    $revenueAccountID = $Obj->GENERATE_PK("tblAccRevenueAccounts");
    $sqlAdd = "INSERT INTO tblAccRevenueAccounts
              SET revenueAccountID = '".$revenueAccountID."',
              outletID = '".$outletID[$x]."',
              accountID = '".$accountID."',
              recipeTypeID = '".$recipeTypeID."',
              dateTimeEmployee = NOW(),
              active = 'y' ";
    $Obj->ExecuteData($sqlAdd, $Obj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS); 
  }   
}
```

Comment: how is that data generated? That is a very unusual structure

Comment: You should look into using prepared statements, but you seem to be using some library for your SQL so not sure how this would be supported.

Comment: @RamRaider im using Kendo Ui grid form. And one of the grid column can be select more than one value.  When submit it sent those structure

Comment: "Sometimes" looks strange. What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$outletID[$x]['OutletID']`, otherways you'll get whole array (outletID, outletName, index, checked, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is a bit weird, but your naming convention is weirder. Anyway updated code below (you where inserting the whole array into the database):

```
$sqlAdd = "INSERT INTO tblAccRevenueAccounts
          SET revenueAccountID = '".$revenueAccountID."',
          outletID = '".$outletID[$x]['outletID']."',
          accountID = '".$accountID."',
          recipeTypeID = '".$recipeTypeID."',
          dateTimeEmployee = NOW(),
          active = 'y' ";
```

PS: Posted from phone, no code formatting available! ( why!? )